# Button setPressed() onClick

Tags: android

this is an easy question,

in my xml file i have :

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_8"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Bf"
android:background="@drawable/button_purple" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:onClick="action"            
/>
```

And in my activity i have that :

```
public void action (View v)
{
    s = "m";
    changeCouleur("blue");
    v.setPressed(true);
}
```

When i pressed the button it's working but the button don't stay pressed.

I don't use an image this is what i use for the color :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#449def" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#449def" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#449def"
                android:endColor="#2f6699"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Thanks in advance if you noticed something wrong.
Please anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work as a view? Try ((Button) v).setPressed(true)

Comment: I tried to cast but that doesn't work.

Comment: ToggleButton doesn't fit with what i trying to do

Comment: You set a drawable and then change the color without removing the drawable?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I want to change the state of the button. Like that i will look like pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand is that you are trying to use a button to turn a state off/on, also the button's state will clearly indicate the feature's state.

If I am correct then use custom check box. You will have to anyways define selector for different states of checkbox (as mentioned by user1071979).

Comment: I think you understand what i trying to do but the solution by user1071979 doesn't help me.

Comment: Well in that case use ToggleButton and in selector define items for android:state_checked="true" & android:state_checked="false"

Answer (score 0):

you have to use two images to do this.

button_normal
button_pressed
then create a xml resource in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />

</selector>
```

then, set this file as a background for the imageview. here we are using imageview as button. dont forget to include those two buttons in the drawable folder.